# Eigen matrices?

Tags: linear-algebra, matrices

Suppose we have a matrix product of two same size square matrices $AB$, then what are the sufficient conditions for this multiplication to be representable as:

$$ AB = \lambda B$$

This is true when $A$ is scaled up identity matrix for all other matrice. But suppose $A$ is an arbitary 'nice' matrix, then what condition need to be imposed on the above equation for such a $\lambda$ to exsist?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The answer to your question will be most clear if you write the matrix $B$ as a matrix of columns, i.e.

$$B=\begin{bmatrix}b_1&b_2&\cdots&b_n\end{bmatrix}$$

where $b_i$ is a column of $n$ values.

Then, since $$AB=\begin{bmatrix}Ab_1&Ab_2&\cdots&Ab_n\end{bmatrix}$$

you can see that your condition, $AB=\lambda B$, is equivalent to the condition

$$\forall i: Ab_i = \lambda b_i$$

which means that if $B$ is of full rank, a scaled identity matrix is the *only* matrix that satisfies your condition.

Comment: I assume you meant by this that for a fixed full-rank $B$, only a scaled-identity matrix $A$ would meet the condition (because the columns of $B$ span all space, so $Av = \lambda v$ for all vectors $v$). But I interpret the question as what conditions must be placed on $\lambda, A$ so that such a non-zero matrix $B$ exists. And of course for that question, ancient mathematician's answer is correct.

Answer (score 6):

The columns of $B$ must lie in the $\lambda$-eigenspace of $A$.